# What is the limit of this sequence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Problem 3 in the Exercises after Chapter 3 in *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

Let $s_1 \colon= \sqrt{2}$, and let 
$$s_{n+1} \colon= \sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}} \mbox{ for } n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots. $$

Then how to rigorously calculate $$\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n,$$ justifying each step from the definition of convergence of a sequence and the theorems on convergence of sequences as have been proved by Rudin upto this point in his book?

I know that this sequence is increasing and bounded (above) and hence convergent.

Comment: What is your upper bound? The limit is $\sqrt 3$ so if you can show that $\sqrt 3$ is supremum then we're good.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned already, $L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$. Also $L \geq 0$. Then

$$ L = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{L}} $$

$$ L^2 = 2 + \sqrt{L} $$

Let $k = \sqrt{L}$. We have

$$k^4 = 2 + k$$

$$(k + 1)(k^3 - k^2 + k - 2) = 0$$

Since $k \geq 0$, we have

$$ k^3 - k^2 + k - 2 = 0$$

which has one positive real root around 1.35. Then $L = k^2$ is around 1.83.

For an exact value of $L$, please see Claude Leibovici's answer.

Comment: Why is $L=\sqrt{ 2+\sqrt L}$?

Comment: You can pass the limit since square root and plus are continuous functions.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing Cheung SW's answer and solving the cubic, we get $$k=\frac{1}{3} \left(1-2 \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{47+3 \sqrt{249}}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}
   \left(47+3 \sqrt{249}\right)}\right)\approx 1.35321$$ and then $$L=\frac{1}{3} \left(-1+\sqrt[3]{\frac{79}{2}-\frac{3
   \sqrt{249}}{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(79+3 \sqrt{249}\right)}\right)\approx 1.83118$$